# Why does Pydantic evaluate Optional values after or as None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, pylance

I have a method which returns an instance of a class depending on a user's successful authentication.

```py
account: Optional[Account] = await Account.authenticate(email, password)
return account or account.dict()
```

From my understanding, since None type is Falsey any occurance of account after the `or` keyword should be of type `Account`.

Any insight into why this is reporting an error would be greatly appreciated.

I have already looked for other instances in Pylance's GitHub issues for values after or being reported as `None`.

Comment: Are you getting an error at runtime or in your IDE?

Comment: I'm getting this error in my IDE it works as expected at runtime.

Comment: what about `return None if account is None else account.dict()`

Comment: Only if `account` is None (or other falsy value) is the `account.dict()` part of the expression evaluated - this is the exact opposite of what you want.

Comment: That works @Samathingamajig but I'm asking this question to understand the failure. Based on my assumptions from how typing should work in python the `or` method should work, right?

Comment: Yep, pylance is just being dumb here

Comment: If `account` is `None`, then `account.dict()` is an error. I think you mean `return account and account.dict()`. (If `account` is `None`, the entire expression is `None`; if `account` is not `None`--and presumably truthy--the expression has `account.dict()` as its value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your IDE is correct.

Consider what happens when the `authenticate()` method returns `None`. You return:

```py
account or account.dict()
```

It doesn't return `account`, as you state, because `account` is falsy. However, you then call `None.dict()`, which would be a typing error.

You should change `account.dict()` to some value that doesn't invoke an instance method of `None`, but what that value is depends on context that isn't provided in the question.